# How to reduce cylinder faces?

Tags: mesh, geometry

How can I reduce those cylinder faces so that theres just one face for each two faces? I want to make fitting teeth for the tooth gear nearby and the faces are too small.

[image]

Comment: I would select all the longer edges, check or deselect, and dissolve, but that may not work for you.

Comment: Thanks you're a hero! I was looking at the cleanup functions but none did work!

Comment: praise The Lord.

Comment: you meant Select > Checker Deselect